# How do I use a 'foreign key' as criteria in a LINQ to Entities query?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a Departments table, which has a foreign key column to Sites, on Department.SiteId = Sites.SiteId.  Now in my EF model, my Departments entity doesn't have a Siteid attribute, just a reference to Sites.  How do I select, in a LINQ query, all departments with a specific SiteId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = 
    from d in entities.Departments
    where d.Site.SiteId == theSiteId
    select d;
```

Comment: So simple, yet so elusive.  Thanks! I was looking all over for SitesReference.EntityKey etc.